# Has Toad Been Shown to Spit Quick Drying Adhesive Slime Prior to the first X-Men Movie?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

Found this on the website Comic Vine recently: Toad’s body also secretes a quick drying adhesive that he spits at his opponents. It wraps around them and dries instantly, incapacitating them unless they can break free.

Later, it is implied that this was adapted to the films, where he used it on Jean Grey. So, my question is, has Toad been shown to be able to spit quick drying adhesive slime prior to his portrayal by Ray Park in the first X-Men film?

Comment: Is this a troll question?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? I tried to search for Synger (or related) interviews stating they had reworked Toad, statements from Marvel guys which would say something along the lines of "we changed comics Toad to match the movie", but to no avail so far. I'm reasonably sure this has _never_ showed up in the comics prior to the movie, but that's not really a good answer.

Comment: I'm just trying to determine if the ability has shown up in the comics before the film, or if the film was the first instance

Comment: Yeah, that I understood, but what I'm saying is that what kind of _proof_ are you looking for? As said above I think it was a movie upgrade, but I didn't find an "official" quote stating this (doens't mean there isn't one, of course). _Assuming_ there isn't one, the only answer left would be someone saying "I've read all the comics featuring Toad, and there wasn't such a thing" - which may be tru,e but is also borderline in terms of evidence

Comment: It looks to be a mashup of two of his abilities - the acidic spit and the quick drying paralytic resin both of which were obtained after his genetic damage due to the black womb project was corrected (This happens just before the Blood-Sport arc as he spits a bunch of his acidic spit on wolverine during it) [Though he could have obtained it later as I know he even gets a flaming tongue later in the comics and I have not read each and every one of them]

Comment: @Jenayah-As far as proof goes, I do not mind if someone states that they've read all the comics featuring Toad up to that point and he didn't use the ability, but only if they have some kind of way to back the claim. I'm also willing to accept answers based on interviews or comments from someone involved (maybe Ray Park or Bryan Singer, or one of the producers mentioned it during production?)

Comment: @casualcoder-If you can find any evidence supporting this or something similar, that would be great, although I am pretty sure the Blood-Sport arc happened after the movie had come out. Also, the flaming tongue is a fairly recent addition, so you definitely have some catching up to do.

Comment: @Endgame-Nope, this is completely serious.

Comment: Been doing some research, Toad appeared to be closest to his movie counterpart in X-Men (2nd series), especially around issue #107, a few months after the film released. Maybe this will help.